# How to toggle on both sides in feinstein's SlidingMenu (Left_Right mode) using icons in ActionBar?

Tags: android, icons, android-actionbar, slidingmenu

I am using feinstein's SlidingMenuActivity. I had set the mode in LEFT_RIGHT and I would like my application to have two icons in the action bar where they automatically will toggle the view between left layout - central layout and central layout - right layout respectively. The first toggle is easy using home icon. However I cannot find a way doing that for the right side. Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
.
.
.
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
               menu.toggle();
                return true;

            case R.id.second_icon:
                // do toggle between central and right layout
                return true;

            }
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
}
```

I have to deal with two problems:

1. First of all the second icon does not respond (it doesn't get inside case R.id.second_button).
2. toggle() changes the view between left and central layout in Left_Right Mode. Is there any way to do that between central and right layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `showSecondaryMenu()`

cheers :)